# Spring Boot, Docker-Compose: Always defaults to port 80

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose

I created my docker container using the suggested Dockerfile in Spring docs:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

application.properties:

```
server.host=localhost
server.port=80
```

Docker-compose.yml specifying the port as 88:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    app:
        image: app:latest
        container_name: app
        network_mode: host
        ports:
            - 8888:8888
```

But whenever I launch my app, it defaults to port 80, ignoring the ports field in docker-compose.yml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified :

```
network_mode: host
```

It means that the host network is used.
So the application is reachable on `80` (the host port) and that 's all.

To make it available on 8888, use a correct mapping :

```
- 8888:80
```

That publishes on the port `8888` of the host (first value) what you get on the port `80` of the container (second value).

Comment: Thanks. Silly mistake was I didn't open the browser to see where the app is running.  It was indeed running on the correct port, but the Tomcat running inside the container always said port 80 so I got confused.  thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. That may indeed be confusing at the beginning :)

Comment: hi would you mind helping me on a similar issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74233854/docker-compose-on-jenkins-pipeline-not-working

Answer (score 2):

This section of code simply create a DNAT from your host:8888 to the container:8888

```
ports:
  - 8888:8888
```

Your spring boot must listen on 8888, otherwise the DNAT rule will point to a dead port.

This is likely to be related to your `application.properties`/`application.yml`.
Look for `server.port=80` in these files.

Comment: hi would you mind helping me on a similar issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74233854/docker-compose-on-jenkins-pipeline-not-working