# Docker compose on Jenkins Pipeline not working

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run both servers Phpmyadmin (using xamp) and my spring application at the same time using my docker-compose.yaml file.

I get this exception error that asks me to enable a connection.

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

I'm actually launching jenkins using my centos virtual machine via vagrant. My spring boot project is in my local machine. Do you guys think I should be opening xamp/wamp for it to work?

Here is a part of my jenkins pipeline script:

```
stage('Building our image') {
             //docker build successful
        }
        
 stage('Deploy our image') {
             //docker push successful (deployed on dockerhub)
    }
    
    stage('Docker compose') {
            steps {
               
            sh 'docker-compose up'
            sh 'docker-compose logs'
               
            }
        }
```

Here's my Dockerfile (8090 is the port in my application propreties):

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8090
ADD target/achat-1.0.jar achat-1.0.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/achat-1.0.jar"]
```

Here's my "docker-compose.yml"

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  mysqldb_standalone:
  
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql:8
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
    
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: achat
      
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  spring_boot_project:
  
    image: achat

    container_name: achat

    build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: Dockerfile

    ports:
      - 9050:9050

    depends_on:
      - mysqldb_standalone
```

My application.propreties:

```
#Server configuration
server.servlet.context-path=/SpringMVC
server.port=8082

### DATABASE ###
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/achatdb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
### JPA / HIBERNATE ###
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

#logging configuration
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO 
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %-5level - %logger{60} - %msg%n
```

Comment: The default Spring Boot HTTP port is 8080; your Dockerfile says `EXPOSE 8090`; your Compose file says `ports: ...:9050`.  Which port is your application actually listening on?  What code or connection is producing the exception you quote?

Comment: @DavidMaze Hi thanks for your reply! I checked the output and it says "Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)". Should I change it to 8080? What could you suggest me to solve this issue!

Comment: @DavidMaze I just realized that the name of my database in application propreties  and the one in the docker compose are not the same, i'll fix that and I'll let you know if my issue is solved

Comment: If the application is listening on port 8090, then that port number needs to be the second `ports:` number as well.

Comment: @DavidMaze I made it 9050:8090 and nothing changed. Actually I really got confused , database I'm using is in phpmyadmin (launched by xamp). The database is not in local mysql

Comment: Hey again @DavidMaze , I updated my question and I added my appilcationpropreties file , thought you could have a look